# What is the best method to determine statistical differences between percentages that do NOT satisfy ANOVA assumptions?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, percentage

I am working a project where I analyzed image classification accuracy percentages for three algorithms. I laid out 36 plots in an agricultural field and took aerial images over a period of 5 (non-consecutive days). Each of the three algorithms was run on each plot. After classifying the images, I had overall accuracy assessment percentages ranging from 0.93-0.98. A picture of some (modified) data is attached, for reference.

[image]

What is the best method to test for statistical differences (in accuracy) between the three algorithms? Even after doing a Box-Cox data transformation, I do not think ANOVA will work here because my samples are not independent. I have also considered using a chi-squared goodness of fit test, but I'm still not sure how I could detect statistical differences with this.

Note: I am working in R 3.6.2

Comment: The five measurement days for each algorithm are obviously not independent. Do you have any idea about the relationship between all five measurement days within each algorithm modality ? I mean, your conclusions will depend on what you are looking at.

Comment: @Rodolphe I would like to compare the means of the three algorithms across all treatment days and determine significant differences. Cannot use ANOVA because of that assumption violation. I’m looking for an appropriate alternative.

Comment: To me, what you actually want is to compare the three models between each other based on some measure of their fitness or rightness

Comment: Comparing models to find "the best" in term of one criteria or another is best done using R2 or RMSE (~sum of squared residuals) or some information criterion like AIC or BIC.

Comment: Because the five measurements in each plot are not independent, it is not possible IMHO to treat "time" as a proper treatment factor. Doing so would result in pseudoreplication and biased estimates of models parameters, because the 5 measurements are more similar to each other, being measured on one plot only, than 5 truly independent replicates.

Comment: What you can do however, is to fit your models to data of the 36 plots in day 1, then compare their performance on day 1. Then doing all again for day 2, etc... You will then have, for each day, the "best performing" model according to the criterion of performance you will have used

Comment: But please do not "brutally" fit each model to the whole dataset of all 5 days.

Comment: Once one model is fitted to all dataset of day X,  the criterion of performance or fitness of your choice, for each of the three models. And use that to compare models between each other on day X.

Comment: This seems like a poorly designed study that complicates and limits the statistical analysis?